# How to map points on a curve on another curve? (and how to generalize it to surfaces)

Tags: analysis

The question is quite simple and I think is (more or unless) trivial for a 1D shapes like curves, but I don't know how to do it for surfaces. I have to say that I am not a mathematician, so I apologise for all the mistakes or if my question is not very rigorous.

Let $C_f$ the curve associated to the function $f(x)=1$, and $c={c_0,c_1,...}$ a set of points that are on the curve $C$. For the simplicity of this example, let's say that $c$ are equally spaced, so that $c_0=(-1,0)$, $c_1=(-1,1)$ and so on. Let $C_g$ the curve associated to the function $g(x)=-\exp(|x|)$.

What I am looking for it the coordinates of the points $c$ when the curve $C_f$ is "sticked" to the curve $C_g$, in other words in this case I am looking for the coordinates of points that are equally spaced by a distance of 1 unit on the curve $C_g$.

I don't know if there is a method known in maths for that, and if the problem is easy to generalize to 2D. My true goal is to "stick" a set of points that are defined on a hemisphere on a 2D surface.

I am looking for any advices, or already existing methods.